# Where does __import__ get alias names from?

Tags: python, import, alias

Python allows aliasing of imports, through `...as <ALIAS>` clauses in the import statement, like this:

```
import mymodule as somealias
from myothermodule import spam as spamalias, ham as hamalias
```

Now, in the default case at least, import statements, including those that have `as`-clauses like the ones above, result in calls to `__builtin__.__import__` whose arguments lists do *not* include the names of such aliases.  IOW, AFAICT, the following "aliasing-free" import statements produce identical calls to `__builtin__.__import__` as do the import statements quoted above:

```
import mymodule
from myothermodule import spam, ham
```

So how do these alias names enter the import process?  And does Python provide ways to customize how alias names are used by the import process?

(I don't have any specific application in mind; I'm just trying to better understand how Python works.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `__import__()` does not bind any names in the calling scope.  Basically,

```
import foo
```

is similar to

```
foo = __import__("foo")
```

and

```
import foo as bar
```

is similar to

```
bar = __import__("foo")
```

Name binding happens in the calling scope, not inside the function, so `__import__()` does not *need* to know what name the module will finally be bound to.

This can also be seen from the CPython byte code of these statements:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("import foo", "", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (foo)
              9 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile("import foo as bar", "", "exec"))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (foo)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (bar)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `IMPORT_NAME` opcode implicitly calls `__import__()` and leaves the resulting module on the internal stack.  The subsequent `STORE_NAME` pops the module from the stack and binds it to a local name.  You can see the only difference between the two snippets is which name the module gets stored to.

Comment: Great answer, and lightning-fast.  I'll accept it as soon as SO let's me.  Thanks!